# Is it possible to call a Python 3.2 function in Python 3.4 program?

Tags: python, pickle, python-3.4, python-3.2

I want to use a commercial package only supporting python 3.2. However lots of packages supporting python 3.4 cannot be easily installed in 3.2.

So is it possible to let a python 3.4 program call a python 3.2 function?

---

My walk around method is to write a python 3.2 program, using `pickle` to save the function output:

```
# python 3.2, function.py
with open("temp.pickle",'wb") as pickle_output:
    pickle.dump(output,pickle_output)
```

and call it in a python 3.4 program using:

```
# python 3.4 main.py
subprocess.call("c:\python32\python function.py")
```

then read the pickle in:

```
# python 3.4 main.py
with open("temp.pickle",'wb") as pickle_input:
    input = pickle.load(pickle_input)
```

And use the input object in python 3.4

---

It worked, but slow, and seems silly. Is there any other way to do this? Something like `import module using python 3.2`?

Comment: Did you try to import the package from 3.4?

Comment: @kirbyfan64sos I did, and get: `ImportError: Module use of python32.dll conflicts with this version of Python.`

Comment: Use a subprocess from Py3.4 to run the Py3.2 command and use the output directly?

Comment: This probably won't work, but it's worth a try: could you replace the python32.dll that the module uses with the python34.dll, i.e. copy python34.dll onto python32.dll.

Comment: @kirbyfan64sos I tried and got the same error.╮(╯▽╰)╭

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be using the [shelve module](https://docs.python.org/3.2/library/shelve.html#module-shelve). It provides a slightly higher-level `dict`-style interface to the file used for storing the values. Another possibility too is using the [marshall module](https://docs.python.org/3.2/library/marshal.html), but this will only work for some types, and isn't normally meant to be used. It might be faster in this case.

And yet a third option is to use the [multiprocessing module](https://docs.python.org/3.2/library/multiprocessing.html?highlight=multiprocessing#multiprocessing) to communicate in real time between the processes and to handle starting and stopping them, too.